# Changing background in Launcher

Tags: android, wallpaper, launcher

Is there a way, either programmatic or with user gestures, to change the background of the launcher app?

It's a dismal black background.  I'd like a sunny yellow.   How to do this!?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

There is no "the launcher app" in Android. There are dozens of "launcher apps" (a.k.a., home screens), all written independently, and there are no APIs for most of them.

Comment: True, you can launch apps from the Home Screens.  However, my perspective differs from yours.  The Home Screens contain widgets, icons, and notification updates (separate from status bar).  The launcher contains ONLY app icons.

The Home Screens support settable wallpaper; the Launcher, I'm still looking for that feature.   Bottom line: please review the difference between Launcher, and Home Screens.

Comment: whoops sorry -- that came off ruder than I intended.  I'm glad to have your perspective on questions like this, and thanks for sending your thoughts.   I'm going to buy your book now (really). -- Peter

Comment: @Peter vdL: What you think of as the "launcher" is a feature of a home screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no easy, universal way (for either a programmer or a user) to change the background of the Launcher app or apps.